# Why can't I change the background color of a ggplot legend box to white? (Other colors work fine)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recolor the legend of my ggplot object by adding `theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))`, but the legend remains gray. Oddly, this code works when I choose a colour other than `"white"`.

Here is a small example with some dummy data:

```r
## Dummy data
response <- rnorm(60, 50, 4)
year <- rep(c(1:10), 6)
treatment <- c(rep("A",30), rep("B", 30))
group <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20))
mydata <- data.frame(response, year, treatment, group)


library(ggplot2)

plot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(
       x = year,
       y = response,
       linetype = treatment,
       color = as.factor(group)
   )) +  geom_smooth()

## Specifying 'white' fill
plot + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

```r
## Specifying 'blue' fill
plot + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "blue"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I've tried a few things with `guide_legend()` but I can't seem to crack it.

How can I turn the legend box white?

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides setting the `fill` for the `legend.key` you have to set the `fill` color of the `key_glyphs` to `white` or `NA` via e.g. `guide_legend`. The reason is that the `grey` fill color in the legend keys reflects the fill color of the standard error ribbons drawn by `geom_smooth`:

```r
response <- rnorm(60, 50, 4)
year <- rep(c(1:10), 6)
treatment <- c(rep("A",30), rep("B", 30))
group <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20), rep(3, 20))
mydata <- data.frame(response, year, treatment, group)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(
  x = year,
  y = response,
  linetype = treatment,
  color = as.factor(group)
)) +  
  geom_smooth() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)),
         linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA))) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know why this overriding only happens for a white background?

Comment: Hej @CaptainHat. What theme do you have in mind? I just checked on my company theme which uses a grey background both for the plot and the panel. There it is the same

Comment: The odd part of the problem is that if you specify `fill = "blue"`, it changes, but for `white` it stays at the default gray. I've tested this on my machine and it's the same. I'm guessing this is to do with `"white"` colour being overwritten by defaults, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @CaptainHat. Okay. Now I see what you mean. Actually the issue is the same. The key glyph for the ribbon also has `alpha<1`. When you use a `blue` fill it's just hard to see that there is an overlayed grey with an opacity < 1. You can check that by adding alpha=1 to geom_smooth. In that case you will get a grey box even with a blue fill.